# Sending a plain text password to nodejs express server. Am I overthinking password security?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, axios, passwords

Apologies in advance if this is a daft question, I'm still learning and I can't find an answer online which makes me think I might have overthought myself into a corner.

**Situation**
I have a little "social network" React app that requires the user to register and set a password using standard html input fields.

The password is then sent via axios to a node.js express server where it is salted and hashed, then stored in a postgreSQL database.

**My question** is, is sending the plain text password to the backend secure, or should I be salting and hashing at the front end before sending it back to be saved in the database? And, if the latter, can you recommend a good online resource that would show me how to do that?

**Code** is on GitHub -
Registration component: https://github.com/lucywho/qiras-folk/blob/main/src/registration.js
Password hashing and saving: https://github.com/lucywho/qiras-folk/blob/main/index.js (relevant lines are 103-128)
(for completion, salting happens here: https://github.com/lucywho/qiras-folk/blob/main/bc.js)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/q/110415/72084

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending it as plain text is fine so long as it is over HTTPS. The password (and everything else in the request besides the hostname) will be encrypted.

Everything else you are doing like using bcrypt and salting seems fine.

Comment: Thank you. So file under "overthinking" then!